# Do you always need to use coalesce in a WHERE if there can be null/empty values in the columns you're comparing?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I know can't compare columns that are empty/null to others so often times I find myself writing a query like:

```
WHERE field2 <> '' AND coalesce(field1, '') <> coalesce(field2, '')
```

This is the way I've always done it, but I'm curious if there's a better way to handle null/empty values. Also I'm curious as to why [`NULL <comparison operator> anything` is `UNKNOWN`](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/c7823064-d03b-441f-82ec-9eb7a1fe6135@2g2000hsn.googlegroups.com) in the first place.

Comment: `WHERE field2 <> '' AND field1 IS DISTINCT FROM field2` (DISTINCT FROM is a postgres extension)

Comment: COALESCE makes it easy by ensuring you compare values, instead of values with non-values.  As for why 3VL, see https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL) for a bit of background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The use of `COALESCE()` generally prevents indexes from being used.  The equivalent syntax using boolean logic gets cumbersome.

The best solution is to use `IS DISTINCT FROM`:

```
where field1 is distinct from field2
```

By using built-in operators, there is a better change that Postgres can optimize the query.  `IS DISTINCT FROM` is ANSI standard syntax which is explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-comparison.html).

Comment: Why does coalesce prevent indexes from being used?

Comment: @AR7 . . . In almost any database, almost any function on a column prevents the use of indexes.  There are exceptions here and there, but in general, functions prevent the use of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

A small note: the result for `(COALESCE(t1.val, '') <> COALESCE(t2.val, ''))` and `(t1.val IS DISTINCT FROM t2.val)` is **not** the same, since `'' <> NULL` is NULL. Example truth table:

```
CREATE TABLE three
        ( id serial not null primary key
        , val text
        );
insert into three(val) VALUES(NULL), ('') , ('a') , ('b' );



SELECT COALESCE(t1.val, '<NULL>' ) AS t1val     -- <NULL> for readability
        ,COALESCE(t2.val, '<NULL>' ) AS t2val   -- <NULL> for readability
        , (t1.val <> t2.val) AS is_ne
        , (COALESCE(t1.val, '') <> COALESCE(t2.val, '')) AS coa_is_ne
        , (t1.val IS DISTINCT FROM t2.val) AS is_distinct
FROM three t1, three t2
ORDER BY t1.val,t2.val
        ;
```

---

Resulting truth table:

```
 t1val  | t2val  | is_ne | coa_is_ne | is_distinct 
--------+--------+-------+-----------+-------------
        |        | f     | f         | f
        | a      | t     | t         | t
        | b      | t     | t         | t
        | <NULL> |       | f         | t          # <<-- here
 a      |        | t     | t         | t
 a      | a      | f     | f         | f
 a      | b      | t     | t         | t
 a      | <NULL> |       | t         | t
 b      |        | t     | t         | t
 b      | a      | t     | t         | t
 b      | b      | f     | f         | f
 b      | <NULL> |       | t         | t
 <NULL> |        |       | f         | t          # <<-- and here
 <NULL> | a      |       | t         | t
 <NULL> | b      |       | t         | t
 <NULL> | <NULL> |       | f         | f
(16 rows)
```