# Why do functions on columns prevent the use of indexes?

Tags: sql, database, indexing

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898534/do-you-always-need-to-use-coalesce-in-a-where-if-there-can-be-null-empty-values) that I asked the other day I got the following comment.

> In almost any database, almost any function on a column prevents the use of indexes. There are exceptions here and there, but in general, functions prevent the use of indexes

I googled around and found more mentions of this same behavior, but I had trouble finding something more in depth than what the comment already told me.

Could someone elaborate on why this occurs, and perhaps strategies for avoiding it?

Comment: There are functional indexes at least in Oracle. That is maybe one of the exceptions here and there :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An index in its most basic form is just the sorted column data, making it easy to look up by some value. For example, a textbook can have the pages in some order, but then have an index in the back for all the terms. As you can see, the data is precomputed/sorted and stored in a separate area.

When you apply a function to the column and try to match/filter based on the output, the index is no longer useful. Let's take a look at our book example again, and say that the function we're applying is the reverse of the term (so `reverse('integral')` becomes `'largetni'`). You won't find this value in the index, so you have to take all the terms, put them through the function, and only then compare. All at query time. Originally we could skip search for `i`, then `in`, then `int` and so on, making it easy to find the term so the function made everything much slower.

If you query using this function often, you could make an index with `reverse(term)` ahead of time to speed up look ups. But without doing so explicitly, it will always be slow.

Answer (score 2):

The indexes are stored separately from the data itself on the SQL server. So when you do a query the B-tree index that ought to be  referenced to provide the speed can no longer be referenced because there is an operation(the function) on each of the column so the query optimiser will opt not to use the index any more.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good explanation of why this occurs (this is a SQL Server specific article, but probably applies to other SQL RDBMS systems):

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1236/avoid-sql-server-functions-in-the-where-clause-for-performance/

The line from the article that really stands out is "The reason for this is is that the function value has to be evaluated for each row of data to determine it matches your criteria."

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider an extreme example.  Let's say that you're looking up a row using a cryptographic hash function, like `HASH(email_address) = 0x123456`.  The database has an index built on `email_address`, but now you're asking it to look up data on `HASH(email_address)` which it doesn't have.  It *could* still use the index, but it would end up having to look at every single index entry for `email_address` and see if `HASH(email_address)` matches.  If it's going to have to scan the full index, it may as well just scan the full table instead so it doesn't have to bounce back and forth fetching individual row locations.