# Better way to assign MAX values to variables?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to define a Variable ("COUNT") as the count of a query so that I can use it in my conditional statement later in my PLSQL block. I get the count using the following syntax:

```
Select count(value_tx) from value where trunc(date) = trunc(sysdate)
```

The only way I know how to do this currently is to use a cursor. Is there a better way to do this? My approach using the cursor is as follows:

```
Create or Replace Procedure TEST IS
CURSOR C1 is
select count(value_tx) as COUNTE
  from value
  where trunc(date) = trunc(sysdate)
  group by hr_utc;
l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
Open c1;
        FETCH c1 into l_var;
        IF l_var.counte > 0 THEN  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_var.COUNTE);
        END IF;
Close c1;
END TEST;
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on what more you want to do with those results. You just want to print them? Your code is ok (you could change that to a for loop). Another thing: you're showing the count, but not the hr_utc value to which is associated, which I think it would be helpful. Otherwise, you'll be seing some values, but not to which group is associated.

Comment: How about using CASE instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what is a "better way" for you. An alternative is a [`FOR` loop with an implicit cursor over a `SELECT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155) .

```
FOR R IN (SELECT COUNT(VALUE_TX) AS COUNTE
                 FROM VALUE
                 WHERE TRUNC(DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                 GROUP BY HR_UTC) LOOP
  IF R.COUNTE > 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(R.COUNTE);
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

It's a convenient syntactical shortcut, if that's something you count as "better" here.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to do this?

Sure it is.
The problem is this condition: `where trunc(date) = ....`. This prevent RDBMS from using an an index on `date` column. If the table is big, this can cause performance problems. I am not going to explain the reason, you can find an explanation elsewhere, for example here: [Why do functions on columns prevent the use of indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927069/why-do-functions-on-columns-prevent-the-use-of-indexes)

You need to replace this condition with:

```
 `where date >= trunc(sysdate) AND date < trunc(sysdate) + 1
```

or

`where date >= trunc(sysdate) AND date < trunc(sysdate) + interval '1' day`

Comment: i did some reading, that makes sense. thanks so much for pointing that out

Comment: @John Wick - do some reading on aggregate functions and implicit cursors. Aggregate functions always return a single row. All of above cab be done w/out pl/sql at all. Or at least with a single cursor.

Comment: if i want to not use functions (since it may lead to performance problems), what would be the optimal way of doing it in your opinion?